# Removing something from an array

Tags: java, arrays

This is a part of my code where I have an array (shapes) and need to be able to remove and add a shape from this array. In the if statement, if I take out the " && shapes[i].equals(aShape)" part, it will remove the shape from the array but even if the user enters a shape that isn't in the array. How can I get it to only remove a shape in the array if they enter a shape that is actually there?

If I add a circle, and choose to remove said circle, it just tells me "Cannot find that shape."

```
//Remove Shape
public void removeShape(Shape aShape)
{
    for(int i=0;i<shapes.length;i++)
    {
        if(shapes[i] != null && shapes[i].equals(aShape))
        {
            shapes[i] = null;
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Cannot find that shape.");
}
```

Comment: Where's your `Shape` class? Did you implement `equals()`?

Comment: Have you implemented `equals` in your Shape class?

Comment: @shmosel I thought `.equals` meant it was comparing the shapes like it would if you used it to compared strings? I'll try it

Comment: If you want to *remove* from an array, then you mean shrinking the array size right? rather than setting null to it.

Comment: @PSo no not necessarily. I want to be able to remove a value from the array but keep it the same size. The sample code I used to write this was the exact same format so I'm not sure why this isn't working

Comment: Let's make it simple, equals means Object comparison, if you do not implement your own, you will be using this one, which compare the memory address to see if the objects are identical, i would recommend you to write your own equals methods. I will write a piece of sample code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default implementation of **equals()** class provided by java.lang.Object compares memory location and only return true if two reference variable are pointing to same memory location

i.e. essentially they are same object.

So in your case, since Shape is an interface, you have to add your own **equals** method, in my example is *compare*, in your Shape Interface.

```
public interface Shape {
    //Your variable and methods are skipped
    public boolean compare();
}
```

---

```
public class Circle extends Shape {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean compare(String name) {
        if (this.name.equals(name)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

If you do not want to implement compare in every classes, you can use static method in an interface, (default method will also work but i am not famil

```
public interface Shape {
    //Your variable and methods are skipped
    public static boolean compare(String name1, String name2){
        if (name1.equals(name2)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

The if you will be using it in this way:

```
//Remove Shape
public void removeShape(Shape aShape)
{
    for(int i=0;i<shapes.length;i++)
    {
        if(shapes[i] != null && Shape.compare(shapes[1].name, aShape.name))
        {
            shapes[i] = null;
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Cannot find that shape.");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great, however, instead of a Shape _class_, I have a Shape _interface_, as per instructions. Could I just add this into my front-end or something or does it have to be in the shape class?

Comment: If you have an interface, you can also implement similar method into it, but for actual implementation, you can only make instance of class

Comment: So i guess you have some classes like *Circle*, *Triangle* which extends this interface?

Comment: The logic is similar, implement your own method, may not be equals if you want, in the Shape interface. I updated the ans as reference

Comment: @DanielZippel see if you have further questions.

Comment: The UML diagram says it should be possible without the equals method. Still trying to figure it out

Comment: @DanielZippel Sure it's possible, just compare the properties directly in the loop. It was your decision to call `equals()` that we were commenting on.